# 2022 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2022 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: Due to the very low number of votes so far in the election (as well as [a bug](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/759/20202) causing some votes to not be recorded), **the voting phase of this election has been extended by 1 week**. The election will now conclude at 20:00 UTC on October 18, 2022.

Comment: Since we found (and fixed) a bug preventing some votes from being saved, I made a new post here as a reminder: [The moderator election has been extended until October 18, 2022 – please check your ballots to ensure your selections have been saved!](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/763/20202)