# During the election, the choice is not properly saved in Ballot

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, election

I am voting to the current moderator election [here](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/election/) but when I modify the `Ballot` position event the box is saying "Selections saved" after the 5 seconds delay, if I just refresh the page, my last modification is lost.

I initially did the same and did not get the badge until Yesterday when by chance my vote has been really saved.

This is quite annoying as I do not know if my selection is really effective and time consuming if I have to redo it several times.

I am not sure if I missed some action but I scroll all the page to find if there is a button to force the save of the selection and found nothing. I assume the `Ballot` box is taking the votes after the 5 second delay.

I am using Google Chrome Browser from MAC OSX 10.15.7 (Catalina).

**Update:**
steps to reproduce

After seeing the answers, I arrive to the conclusion that this is the "Undo" user which seems to have the bug.

If I clean the Ballot by removing all Jeff Schaller, after 5 sec the ballot is really empty (and saved).
Now if I want to vote for "Undo", and put only him in the Ballot (position #1), after 5 seconds the ballots say "saved" but when I refresh the ballot is still empty.
If I do this for Jeff Schaller, the selection is saved, but I cannot put "Undo" in the ballot in 2nd position as well.

Comment: I wonder if there's any funky going on with javascript? I tried to reproduce this, but my ballot stayed the same during each refresh. Given that you received the badge (at 2022-10-05 19:05:45Z system time), I'm inclined to believe that your ballot was cast as you intended, but I obviously can't confirm that.

Comment: I am seeing the same thing. I've tried to vote on a Firefox browser and on Chrome mobile. I didn't see any JS errors on Firefox.

Comment: Same thing on Chrome on Ubuntu, Chrome on Android and Edge/Windows. Oh well, it is advertised as beta or perhaps it is the name of one of the candidates.. :)

Comment: I've added the [status-review] tag to create a ticket for us internally so that I can ask the devs to look into this ASAP. For now, y'all may want to give the election page at least a few extra seconds to save the vote just in case, and check your profile to make sure that you've earned the Constituent badge for voting in the final phase of the election.

Comment: Link to the recent Constituent Badger earners (of which, рüффп is one of them): https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/badges/81/constituent

Comment: The devs are having some trouble reproducing this issue... If a user has ranked the candidates by dragging the selection into the "1. (Drag next selection here)" area, then it seems like those votes should get saved. However, if you don't drag the candidates up into that area, then there won't be any selections saved, even though the system shows a message that the ballot has been saved. **Can those of you experiencing this issue confirm that you're dragging the candidate names into that numbered-list portion of the ballot ("1. (Drag next selection here)", etc.)?**

Comment: Curses, my elaborate scheme to win the election has been foiled! (Or, Undo's scheme to throw the election has failed). Hope it's an easy bug to fix!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay - we've fixed it. Thank you for bringing up this issue.

The bug only happens in a very specific set of super unlikely circumstances: we were mistakenly checking the Id of a nomination against the Id of a user (instead of comparing UserId to UserId), and when those overlapped, that user's nomination was incorrectly marked as withdrawn. It was never caught because this situation is remarkably unlikely so we weren't able to find any issues while testing.

This has some ramifications for this election, so look out for a post from a Community Manager (probably V2Blast) coming soon with more information.

Comment: I made a new post here: [The moderator election has been extended until October 18, 2022 – please check your ballots to ensure your selections have been saved!](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/763/20202)

Comment: I accept your answer as the bug seems not present anymore. Thanks.
Just a developer's question: was that bug present only in this election or it can has been present for all election processes in all SE communities?

Comment: @рüффп good question - the bug *could have* been present in any election but it was SO wildly unlikely that it only ended up showing up in this particular election.

Comment: This is because of the UserID==1, right? I knew I'd break something with that eventually... :)

Answer (score 3):

Replication steps:

1. Drag Jeff's name to "Drag Next Selection Here"
2. Drag Undo's name to same location
3. Wait for Pending Save count down to complete

This causes the following:

- `POST` is sent to `https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/election/vote-moderators/` with the following payload (I censor'd my fkey) `fkey=CENSOR&electionId=1&candidateIds%5B%5D=743&candidateIds%5B%5D=1`
- A response is received with the following: `{"Success":false,"Message":"Voting not allowed for withdrawn candidates","NewScore":0}`

Comment: Thank you so much! Having the response allowed us to find the bug causing this. I'm working on getting a fix out right now, and once I do, I'll write up a more detailed answer, because it's sort of bonkers.

Answer (score 1):

Per my comment, the devs are having some trouble reproducing this issue:

- If a user has ranked the candidates by dragging the selection into
  the "1. (Drag next selection here)" area, then it seems like those
  votes do get saved.
- However, if you don't drag the candidates up into that area, then
  there won't be any selections saved, even though the system shows a
  message that the ballot has been saved.

**Can those of you experiencing this issue confirm that you're dragging the candidate names into that numbered-list portion of the ballot ("1. (Drag next selection here)", etc.)?**

If you do so and are still experiencing this problem, please post a response with any relevant details that might help the devs dig deeper into the issue.

---

If those experiencing this issue are able to respond, the devs can continue looking into this issue.

In the meantime, the voting phase of this election has been extended by 1 week. That will allow the devs more time to resolve this potential bug, and hopefully ensure that the community is able to successfully vote in the election.

Comment: I've provided my steps in an answer to have good formatting.